# Send downloadable csv using papaparse and streams

Tags: node.js, typescript, csv, stream, papaparse

I have table in postgresql which I want to convert to csv and send as downloadable file to response using streams

I have the following export service:

```
export class ExportService {
  public static toCsv<T>(data:T[], res:Response):void {
    const csv = Papa.unparse(data);
   
  }
}
```

Now, what I want here is to send this `csv` to the response with streams. Could you please help me to get right approach for this?

Comment: you need to provide more details around the Response object,it seems that you are using nestjs .. if so, create readableStream and return a StreamableFile. check the docs -> https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files#example